# flex datagrid autoscrolling

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I am showing the web service data into flex application using datgrid.
I need to show this data scrolling automatically in continuous manner.

Anyone knows how to do this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to dynamically get the data once a certain scroll position is reached, you just need to update the `verticalScrollPosition` property.

Check out [Creating an auto-scrolling DataGrid control in Flex](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/01/31/creating-an-auto-scrolling-datagrid-control-in-flex/) on [FlexExamples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/), I think that's exactly what you're asking.

If you had a dataset that was 100 items and wanted to tween it down to the last one, using TweenMax, you could do something like (though I'm not sure exactly how the datagrid gets the max scroll position:

`TweenMax.to(dataGrid, 1, {verticalScrollPosition:dataGrid.maxVerticalScrollPosition});`

Hope that helps!